# Brightway2 writing the imported database

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, brightway

I created several excel inventory files using the eco invent exchanges.
To run my LCA I successfully imported the database with 0 unlinked exchanges using:

```
imp = bw.ExcelImporter("Inventory_fuelcell.xlsx")
imp.apply_strategies()
imp.match_database("ecoinvent 3.6 cutoff", fields=('name','unit','location'))
imp.match_database("biosphere3", fields=('name','unit'))
imp.match_database(fields=('name', 'unit', 'location'))
imp.statistics()
```

But when I run `imp.write_database()`
I get the following error:

```
Writing activities to SQLite3 database:
0% [######## ] 100% | ETA: 00:00:00
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidExchange                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-1daab0bbe8d8> in <module>
----> 1 imp.write_database()

/opt/anaconda3/envs/Masterarbeit/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bw2io/importers/excel.py in write_database(self, **kwargs)
    257         """Same as base ``write_database`` method, but ``activate_parameters`` is True by default."""
    258         kwargs['activate_parameters'] = kwargs.get('activate_parameters', True)
--> 259         super(ExcelImporter, self).write_database(**kwargs)
    260 
    261     def get_activity(self, sn, ws):

/opt/anaconda3/envs/Masterarbeit/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bw2io/importers/base_lci.py in write_database(self, data, delete_existing, backend, activate_parameters, **kwargs)
    238 
    239         existing.update(data)
--> 240         db.write(existing)
    241 
    242         if activate_parameters:

/opt/anaconda3/envs/Masterarbeit/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bw2data/project.py in writable_project(wrapped, instance, args, kwargs)
    354     if projects.read_only:
    355         raise ReadOnlyProject(READ_ONLY_PROJECT)
--> 356     return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)

/opt/anaconda3/envs/Masterarbeit/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bw2data/backends/peewee/database.py in write(self, data, process)
    258         if data:
    259             try:
--> 260                 self._efficient_write_many_data(data)
    261             except:
    262                 # Purge all data from database, then reraise

/opt/anaconda3/envs/Masterarbeit/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bw2data/backends/peewee/database.py in _efficient_write_many_data(self, data, indices)
    203             for index, (key, ds) in enumerate(data.items()):
    204                 exchanges, activities = self._efficient_write_dataset(
--> 205                     index, key, ds, exchanges, activities
    206                 )
    207 

/opt/anaconda3/envs/Masterarbeit/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bw2data/backends/peewee/database.py in _efficient_write_dataset(self, index, key, ds, exchanges, activities)
    154         for exchange in ds.get('exchanges', []):
    155             if 'input' not in exchange or 'amount' not in exchange:
--> 156                 raise InvalidExchange
    157             if 'type' not in exchange:
    158                 raise UntypedExchange

InvalidExchange:
```

I never had this problem before.
Is there a way to figure out where the invalid exchange is?
But even with the error if I look for `databases` it still shows up.
So it seems like the database was in fact imported.
Can anybody help me what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If we look through the error traceback, we can see the line raising the error:

```
    154         for exchange in ds.get('exchanges', []):
    155             if 'input' not in exchange or 'amount' not in exchange:
--> 156                 raise InvalidExchange
```

This means that at least one exchange doesn't have an `input` or and `amount`. As all your exchanges are linked, they all have `input` values, so the `amount` must be missing. This could be due to a typo in the column field, or off by one errors, etc.

To find it, you could try:

```py
for ds in imp.data:
    for exc in ds['exchanges']:
        if 'amount' not in exc:
            print("Missing `amount` in exc:")
            print("\t", exc)
            print("Dataset", ds['name'], ds['location'])
        elif 'input' not in exc:
            # check just to make sure
            print("Missing `input` in exc:")
            print("\t", exc)
            print("Dataset", ds['name'], ds['location'])
```